# WPF DataGrid cell change auto update database on MS SQL Server using ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I have database on MS SQL server, and "PC" table in it. "PC" table contains CPU, RAM, HDD attributes and etc. And I have WPF form, with dataGrid on it. I added ADO.NET Entity Data Model, so i got my .edmx model. So, if I want to display all records from "PC" table I can use simply this code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    TestDBEntities dataEntities = new TestDBEntities();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

     var query =
     from PC in dataEntities.PC
     select PC;

     dataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();

    }
```

**The key of my question is how can I change database "PC" table cell (on MS SQL Server) immediately when I changed cell in dataGrid?** Im using exactly ADO.NET **Entity Framework**. I guess, I can handle CellEditEnding event, but I don`t know what do inside this method, for example:

```
private void CellEditEnds(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{

    <--- stuff here --->
    dataEntities.SaveChanges();

}
```

If so, we can get cell content, in correct type and paste to appropriate cell in "PC" table in MS SQL server database. But its sloppy as much as possible, I think, and it`s hard to implement for me :) May be you guys know what to do, may be quite different ways?